# How do I split a delimited textfile into separate files, and name each file using the text after the delimiter?

Tags: macos, split, csv

I have a large text file like this:

```
>name1
SEQUENCEA

>name2
SEQUENCEB
```

Each sequence has a different length. I'd like to split the text file to separate the items, and have each file have the name after the '>'. So that:

filename1 = "name1"

```
>protein1
SEQUENCA
```

filename2 = "name2"

```
>protein2
SEQUENCEB
```

Suggestions for doing this in OSX?